electrical conduit to panel connection question
I am in process of designing my solar system, but my questions are pure (IMO) electrical ones:

My PV panels are connected to microinverters which are connected to J-box. I am planning to connect the J-Box to Enphase controller enclosure  by 3/4" metal water-tight conduit. Can I route my conduit from the roof to the side of the controller box or it's preferable (or required) to route it to the bottom of the Controller enclosure? (see pic 1)


I already have a conduit from the Controller enclosure to the garage wall. Main distribution panel is located on the inside garage wall. Conduit will be connected to the unfused AC disconnect located on the exterior wall . (I am having double breakers in the main panel.) Question: Can I place the AC disconnect box on the exterior wall opposite of the main panel (pic 2 on the right) or must I place it with an offset  (pic 2 left)?




Usually in wet conditions, you want a drip loop/somehow for the water to not go into important stuff

Liquid-tight does not mean dry inside. Indeed, all exterior conduit is defined as wet and almost always meets the definition. The only exceptions I'm aware of involve a whole lot of effort, like pressurizing the conduit with dry nitrogen. If coming into the side of an enclosure, come in low enough (close to the bottom) that any water dripping out of it just drains out of the box without crossing any live parts on the way. Condensate will make it wet even if the seals are all "perfect", for instance.

ok, understood. Do you have any feedback on the second question?
